# Overwrite a function after loading .RData file

Tags: r, rdata

Let's say I have function

```
foo <- function (x, y){
    x <- y + 5
}
```

I save my work with `save.image(file= file_name)`

Then I load data with `load(file, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Let's say I load the data, but after that I modify my function say:

```
foo <- function (x, y){
    x <- y + 10
}
```

If I run it, it will ignore my new version of function. 
Why does this happend and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

It is working well with me and I couldn't find out why you can't overwrite your function. But here are some thoughts:

- make sure that the new definition has same function name (in your case "foo").
- definitely run the new definition (either in the console or using "RUN" in RStudio).
- try using `load(file)` without determining the environoment. (in this case it will be `envir = parent.frame()`).

hope that could help :)